# Generate TTF via image(s) using PHP?

Tags: php, fonts, gd, truetype

Are there existing libraries for generating .ttf via image(s) using PHP (say, a series of images)? There are several references about creating gdf from images, but I've not yet found examples of ttf-font creation via PHP.

N.B. There are also several online resources that let you upload an image (write a letter in each box on an image template) to be instantly converted to a TTF. http://www.yourfonts.com is one of them

Comment: I've never seen any (desktop) software that can create a .ttf from a bitmap. I think it's almost impossible.

Comment: There are websites that'll try to do this for you as a service, e.g. http://www.fontifier.com/. I'm guessing you're trying to clone one of these?

Comment: http://www.yourfonts.com also lets you turn a bitmap into a font by uploading a picture (draw your fonts on a template. save as jpg. upload)

Answer (score 7):

To my knowledge, there is no such tool.

Creating a TrueType font is a *hugely* difficult enterprise. A font consists of a lot of very complex information (see the "technical notes" in the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truetype) to get a tiny impression). It won't do to just paste a series of images together.

Depending on what you want to do, I suppose you could work around this by building a faux "bitmap font", one image file containing one character, and glue the correct images together to form a sentence. The results will probably be less than perfect, though, because there will be no  [Kerning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerning).

Comment: Sure, but you can use line-detection on an image and do something very basic.

Comment: @Rup yup, but for that you have to vectorize the outlines of each image, an write them into a TTF font. Both not impossible tasks of course, but PHP is not the perfect language for this - especially the first part

Comment: what would be a better language (that runs well on a LAMP server)?

Comment: @ina stuff like this is often done in a compiled language like C or C++. There may be ready-made tools for these tasks - [potrace](http://potrace.sourceforge.net/) may help with the vectorization for example.

Comment: @ina also see this discussion for some hints http://marc.info/?l=batik-users&m=102193580203140&w=2

Comment: Merely some thoughts: start looking into SVG first...?

I might be completely off, but I'm investigating the same idea: how-to generate a font from a website. It's easier to generate a SVG font, because the SVG is much more human understandable. As a second step, you -or the end-user- could convert the SVG-font to a TTF.

As as second note to the discussion (that was held in 2010, we're now four years further): there are also websites like ICOMOON that generate fonts from images. So, the technology to create a TTF online must, indeed, be around. But whether it's in PHP...?