# Create Font from images?

Tags: php, fonts, truetype

I have been looking at such online tools as www.yourfonts.com, and wondered if there is a php script that will take the images from the template and produce a ttf font? If not, how would this be done?

Comment: As pointed out by @Cogicero, possible duplicate of [Generate TTF via image(s) using PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3957941/generate-ttf-via-images-using-php)

Comment: If you want to know about general ways to do this, see http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/1054/building-hand-written-fonts-for-lettering